# Error WebSocketException: Connection to <url> was not upgraded to websocket al intentar conectar cliente con Socket.io y Flutter

Tags: nodejs, flutter, socket.io, websocket

Estoy haciendo una app de navegación. Estoy utilizando Flutter para la App y Node.js para el servidor; para la interacción en tiempo real para la geolocalización estoy utilizando Socket.io. Al intentar conectar la app con el servicio me manda un error:

upgrade to websocket (esto en Flutter)

> WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://:0/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket

Al intentar utilizar postman me manda el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Could not connect to https://programaciongotica.com/driver
11:02:36
Error: Unexpected server response: 400
Handshake Details
Request URL: https://<HOST>/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: YZZYnhdbXylKjds0BFV9qA==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: programaciongotica.com
Response Headers
2: 2
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2022 16:02:36 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.13
Status: 400 Bad Request
0: ​
1: ​
{"code": ,"message":"Bad request"}
```

Comment: Puedes publicar el error como texto? No todos podemos visualizar las imágenes

Comment: Ya se actualizo